# Calling API every 24hr period with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, api, curl

I have my API call that retrieves the information I need to pull data onto my site

However, the API call needs to be called every 24hrs but I cannot use cron

Does anyone have an idea on how I can maybe do this with PHP or perhaps JS?

Here's my (simplified) call:

```
$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
    'username' => 'user',
    'password'=>'pass'
));

/* API URL */
$url = ' *my_api_url_here* ';
  
$ch = curl_init($url);
  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo json_encode($result);

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: what consumes `echo json_encode($result);`? why does it need calling every 24hours its not storing or caching anything, why dont you have cron, there is also online ones which can make a request to your site. you could even use a while loop, but considering you don't have cron most likely you will be restricted to 30 seconds execution time.. yes js can do it too over ajax, but you need users to visit the site. have you thought about changing host?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I can't change host, this is for a client that have their own host. It needs to be every 24hrs the API call sends me a token that changes every 24hr period. I'd rather do it with a cron but I don't have that option unfortunately so I'm looking for an alternative solution.

Comment: plot thickens, why not plop some code on the server (password protected) which provides the token and then from your site grab the token vs trying to post it to your api from theirs, surely at least one of your servers has cron

Comment: @LawrenceCherone the API generates the token, I have to call the API to get the token (every 24hrs) for the system to work, so currently my PHP above works but I have to go to the PHP file and manually refresh to get the token which is less than ideal... I don't think I can change too much on the server - I only have FTP access

Comment: You need some app that launches your php code every 24h or another interval, then you check if is the time to call the API or not. If you can't use cron or similar, then you need to have a PHP process running 24x7, with some `while(true) { ... sleep(...);}` Not a good choice but works.

Answer (score 0):

the best way for calling a code in the specific period times, is the cron job that created for this work

if you use shared hostings platforms such as DA or cPanel or anything else, you can use their cronjob system

[Working with cron jobs in DirectAdmin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6CdQBQk-tuw) = based on youtube search

[Working with cron jobs in cPanel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WzIqEJkK_pM) = based on youtube search

[Working with cron jobs in Webmin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JRT0ulqI8xU) = based on youtube search

[How to setup scheduled tasks in Plesk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ur1_ua9TMXs) = based on youtube search

and if you not, the best solution for cron job in linux based operating systems, is crontab

[Managing Cron Jobs in PHP with Crontab](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/managing-cron-jobs-with-php--net-19428) = based on google search

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the research, but I already stated that I can't use a cron job

Comment: excuse me @cheesycoder. i dont see you wroted cant use cron job ! sorry for my fualt

Comment: That's ok! I appreciate your research :)